# Failure in URL fetching using Nutch

Tags: java, nutch

I have been using nutch to build my own web crawler to search for images through a given seed list, and  I am getting an error, I reinstalled nutch to try crawling again but the error keeps occuring again. What can be the problem?

Some replies on the Nutch list indicate not enough space in the /tmp folder but I am not sure.

Here is my log:

```
Fetcher: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:836)
at org.apache.nutch.fetcher.Fetcher.fetch(Fetcher.java:496)
at org.apache.nutch.fetcher.Fetcher.run(Fetcher.java:532)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.nutch.fetcher.Fetcher.main(Fetcher.java:505)
Error running:
/home/vasan/nutch/runtime/local/bin/nutch fetch -D mapred.reduce.tasks=2 -D mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx1000m -D mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution=false -D mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution=false -D mapred.compress.map.output=true -D fetcher.timelimit.mins=180 /media/sf_vasans_repository/WrkSpcFinal/accurateshooter_com//segments/20151011160429 -noParsing -threads 50
Failed with exit value 255.
```

Any advice would be appreciated. I don't think any problems are present in the configuration files, as they are working fine.

Comment: Please indicate the version of Nutch you are using. Also, please provider more detailed log if available from the hadoop.log file.

Comment: i am sure the nutch version is 1.11 the source of download is http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/nutch/trunk